# How to install Dell power manager?

Tags: dell, power-management, fan

I have a fan noise issue non my Dell xps 13 L322X,

After Googling this issue I found this solution: [Fan noise on Inspiron/XPS Notebook/Vostro Notebook/Mobile Precision/Latitude systems](https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr-be/sln309579/undesired-fan-noises-on-inspiron-xps-notebook-vostro-notebook-mobile-precision-latitude-systems?lang=en). I'm wondering if there is something similar to this in Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can download the dell power manager app for linux. However you may be able to change the settings in the bios.